# Recently added a child to firebase database structure and not working anymore

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

AllUsers Class

```
public class AllUsers {

    private String Name;
    private String Status;
    private String Image;

    public AllUsers (){
    }

    public AllUsers(String name, String status, String Image) {
        Name = name;
        Status = status;
        Image = Image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        Status = status;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return Image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        Image = image;
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);


    noUsersText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.noUsersText);
    mUsersList = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersList);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    UID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");


    mProgressDialogue = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    mProgressDialogue.setMessage("Loading...");
    mProgressDialogue.show();


    mUsersList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<AllUsers> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<AllUsers>()
                    .setQuery(mDatabaseReference, AllUsers.class)
                    .build();

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsers, UsersViewHolder>(options) {

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull AllUsers model) {
            holder.setName(model.getName());
            holder.setStatus(model.getStatus());

            final String userId = getRef(position).getKey();

            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId).child("Data");

                    rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            userName = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Chat.class);
                            intent.putExtra("Recievers_Id", userId);
                            intent.putExtra("Recievers_Name", userName);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.all_users_layout, parent, false);
            return new UsersViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
    mUsersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    return rootView;
}


public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View mView;
    public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        TextView mDisplayName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
        mDisplayName.setText(name);
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        TextView mDisplayStatus = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.display_status);
        mDisplayStatus.setText(status);
    }
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(firebaseRecyclerAdapter != null) {
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Database Structure - https://ibb.co/i70DSy

Before i had all the data was inside the unique id child. I just wanted to make it more readable, so i added a child named data under unique id and inside that stored all the data. But the data isn't showing anymore. I have tried so much to figure out and there isn't even any error showing. It's just showing blank screen, and if I click on the screen where the data is supposed to be, the click listener is working at taking me to the next activity.

Can someone please help me out?

Database

```
{
"Chat" : {
"VwtdCRK0aXQ2bnKe01fy8mYUPqs2" : {
  "VwtdCRK0aXQ2bnKe01fy8mYUPqs2" : {
    "Seen" : false,
    "Timestamp" : 1529515719074
  }
  }
 },
"Users" : {
"VwtdCRK0aXQ2bnKe01fy8mYUPqs2" : {
  "Data" : {
    "Image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/messageplus-cd647.appspot.com/o/Raw%2FVwtdCRK0aXQ2bnKe01fy8mYUPqs2.jpg?alt=media&token=a385e502-1068-4efc-a2d8-bd9037201b5f",
    "Name" : "Akash R",
    "Phone_Number" : "8105571584",
    "Status" : "None of your business",
    "Thumb_image" : "Default",
    "Unique" : "VwtdCRK0aXQ2bnKe01fy8mYUPqs2"
  },
  "Quiz" : {
    "Question1" : {
      "Answer" : "fd",
      "Option1" : "123",
      "Option2" : "qz",
      "Option3" : "fd",
      "Option4" : "fd",
      "Question" : "1"
    },
    "Question10" : {
      "Answer" : "d",
      "Option1" : "v",
      "Option2" : "s",
      "Option3" : "b",
      "Option4" : "d",
      "Question" : "10"
    },
    "Question2" : {
      "Answer" : "dh",
      "Option1" : "fj",
      "Option2" : "dh",
      "Option3" : "dhd",
      "Option4" : "dbdb",
      "Question" : "2"
    },
    "Question3" : {
      "Answer" : "ss",
      "Option1" : "dn",
      "Option2" : "vv",
      "Option3" : "ss",
      "Option4" : "df",
      "Question" : "3"
    },
    "Question4" : {
      "Answer" : "bd",
      "Option1" : "cbd",
      "Option2" : "fdgb",
      "Option3" : "xv",
      "Option4" : "bd",
      "Question" : "4"
    },
    "Question5" : {
      "Answer" : "b",
      "Option1" : "dh",
      "Option2" : "c",
      "Option3" : "b",
      "Option4" : "d",
      "Question" : "5"
    },
    "Question6" : {
      "Answer" : "dhs",
      "Option1" : "janf",
      "Option2" : "shs",
      "Option3" : "dgd",
      "Option4" : "dhs",
      "Question" : "6"
    },
    "Question7" : {
      "Answer" : "c",
      "Option1" : "dhsh",
      "Option2" : "fhsnx",
      "Option3" : "c",
      "Option4" : "cndnx",
      "Question" : "7"
    },
    "Question8" : {
      "Answer" : "cg",
      "Option1" : "bs",
      "Option2" : "ccb",
      "Option3" : "cg",
      "Option4" : "fs",
      "Question" : "8"
    },
    "Question9" : {
      "Answer" : "vb",
      "Option1" : "dhds",
      "Option2" : "cc",
      "Option3" : "cs",
      "Option4" : "vb",
      "Question" : "9"
    },
    "Results" : {
      "VwtdCRK0aXQ2bnKe01fy8mYUPqs2" : {
        "Akash R" : "3"
      }
    }
  },
  "Reviews" : {
    "Review" : "Hiiii"
  }
}
```

}
}

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Sorry look to my edited question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the data under each child of `/Users/VwtdCRK0aXQ2bnKe01fy8mYUPqs2` now, it doesn't have any of the properties that your `AllUsers` class has. Since it seems that you just introduced a `Data` level in your JSON tree, you will need to ensure that your Java classes reflect that. That is quite simple in this case, just introduce a new class that has your `AllUsers` class as a property named `Data`:

```
public class AllUsersRoot {
  public AllUsers Data;
}
```

Now you can wire up this `AllUsersRoot` class to your adapter:

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<AllUsersRoot> options =
        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<AllUsersRoot>()
                .setQuery(mDatabaseReference, AllUsersRoot.class)
                .build();

firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsersRoot, UsersViewHolder>(options) {

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull AllUsers model) {
        holder.setName(model.Data.getName());
        holder.setStatus(model.Data.getStatus());
```

You may need to update a few more references, but they all follow this pattern: dereferencing the `Data` level that you added in the JSON.

Note that in general it is an anti-pattern to mix entity types under a single node. One reason for this is that you'll now end up downloading all questions for each user, even if you don't show them in your view. For better performance, keep entity types separate, so keep top level lists of quizzes and reviews keyed by user. E.g.

```
Users" : {
  "VwtdCRK0aXQ2bnKe01fy8mYUPqs2" : {
    "Image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/messageplus-cd647.appspot.com/o/Raw%2FVwtdCRK0aXQ2bnKe01fy8mYUPqs2.jpg?alt=media&token=a385e502-1068-4efc-a2d8-bd9037201b5f",
    "Name" : "Akash R",
    "Phone_Number" : "8105571584",
    "Status" : "None of your business",
    "Thumb_image" : "Default",
    "Unique" : "VwtdCRK0aXQ2bnKe01fy8mYUPqs2"
  },
},
"Quizes" : {
  "VwtdCRK0aXQ2bnKe01fy8mYUPqs2" : {
    "Question1" : { ... },
    ...
  }
},
"Reviews" : {
  "VwtdCRK0aXQ2bnKe01fy8mYUPqs2" : {
    "Review" : "Hiiii"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to change your database reference to -

```
mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId);
```

For eg:-

```
mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("VwtdCRK0aXQ2bnKe01fy8mYUPqs2");
```